# How can I make a request to an API based on the response from another request? React Hook "useSwr" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can make a request to an API based on the response from another request. I'm making a request to an API and extracting the IP address from the response.

Then I want to make another request to a different API using the IP address as input to the 2nd API. When I try the code below I get the error  `React Hook "useSwr" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

I'm using React, TypeScript and SWR. I had this working with a simple JavaScript code but I think I'm getting confused with React/Typescript/SWR here. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import useSwr from 'swr';

const fetcher = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => fetch(...args).then(response => response.json());

const Webmap: FC = () => {

  const validatorUrl = 'http://url1.com';
  const ipInfoUrl =  'http://url2.com';

  const {data, error} = useSwr(validatorUrl, fetcher);
  const validatorData = data && !error ? data : [];

  if (validatorData.results != null) {
    validatorData.results.forEach(u => {
    const ipAddress= u.ip_address
    console.log(ipAddress)
    // This is where I want to make another request. I want to feed ipAddress to ipInfoUrl
    const {data, error} = useSwr(ipInfoUrl, fetcher);
    const ipData = data && !error ? data : [];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are breacking a golden rule from hook definition:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Here: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching#dependent

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import useSwr from 'swr';

const fetcher = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => fetch(...args).then(response => response.json());

const Webmap: FC = () => {

  const validatorUrl = 'http://url1.com';
  const ipInfoUrl =  'http://url2.com';

  const { data: validationData, error: validationError } = useSwr(validatorUrl, fetcher);
  const { data: ipData, error: ipError } = useSwr(() =>
      // this request wont be called until validationData succeeds
      // use a data from validationData, example:
      ipInfoUrl + '?ip=' validationData.results.ip_address,
      fetcher
  );

  console.log(ipData);
```

Comment: Thank you this helps, but I'd like to be able to do this in a loop. For example, the data returned in validationData is an object, and within the object there is an array I'd like to loop through and get all the IP addresses and then make a request to ipInfoUrl for each ip address in the array. Does that make sense ?